# Destructive TCLunshift

Tags: list, tcl, complexity-theory

Let's say I have a list `{1 2 3 }`. I want to unshift it. Create a list which is `{ 0 1 2 3 }`, without creating a new list. This is to save in complexity. In Perl and Ruby, it is possible, by using unshift. Is there a TCL equivalent?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such command in Tcl, but you can easily make it yourself:

```
proc lunshift {var args} {
    upvar 1 $var list
    set list [linsert $list[set list {}] 0 {*}$args]
}
```

The `[set list {}]` part is a trick to make the list unshared, so no duplicate will be made. See [the Tcl wiki](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/K#c2a6014c2d129837889d8a8000d05e5c3b44e8f6b46cab777c04df8a927bfad2) for details.

Demo:

```
set mylist {1 2 3}
lunshift mylist 0
puts $mylist;  # Result => 0 1 2 3
```